# Can't capture with Regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to capture address data from the following text.

```
<address>
Firstname Lastname<br />
Address 1<br />
ZIP City<br />
Country</address>
```

Regex i tried is     `(?<=>)(.*)(?=<\Q/\Eaddress)`

For some reason it is unable to capture anything.

I am completely new to regex, so i really don't understand anything. I only understand that the following regex i found captures data between

```
(?<="from here")(.*)(?="to here")
```

I was also able to escape the slash.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Dot does not match newlines by default.

Comment: C#? Java? JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you should avoid parsing HTML with regex, but since your case seems a simple non-nested case of  tag, you can capture all data between  tag using following regex and capture data in group 1,

```
(?s)<address>(.*?)<\/address>
```

As your data seems to be present in multiple lines, you will need (?s) flag in regex which enables dot to match a new line characters.

[Here is the Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zaxnkl/1)

And, in your own regex, you needed little correction and use (?s) flag like I described above to make it work. Your version of regex can be corrected and used like this,

`(?s)(?<=>)(.*?)(?=<\/address)` (escaping `/` with `\`)

OR

`(?s)(?<=>)(.*?)(?=<\Q/\Eaddress)` (no need to escape / if you put it between \Q and \E)

[Demo for your regex](https://regex101.com/r/Zaxnkl/2)